# Object shadows having lines doubled

Tags: objects, light, shadows, noise-reduction, splines

[image: Object edges having a doubled up effect, which I can't seems to get rid of]

The shadows of the objects seems to be doubling up and even when moving the object around it flickers.

Eevee
[image]

Cycles
[image]

Comment: How many lights are you using? There is a shadow for each light you add.

Comment: In this object there's three lights added, but when I try even one light it's still the same. In Cycles render engine it looks good but when I switch to Eevee it does this multiple shadow thing, both times in single areal light.